# Pass audience to authorization server when using Swagger generated by springdoc-openai-ui with Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have noticed that when authenticating with my auto-generated Swagger UI client, I do not have access to custom Auth0 permissions—and, in fact, the access token being used to make authenticated requests to my resource server is actually "opaque" (not a valid JWT).

I am using Auth0 as my authorization server abstraction. According to Auth0's docs, one must always pass `audience` in the POST request body when generating a JWT via the client credentials flow.

Going through the the flow by making the various API calls manually, I can generate the JWT correctly. The issue lies in there not being an obvious way to pass the `audience` to Auth0 when using the auto-generated Swagger UI client—any ideas?

Library versions:

- Spring Boot starters (e.g., `rest`, `jpa`, `web`)
- `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui` 1.3.9
- `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-data-rest` 1.4.0

**Update**

I have realised that it is possible to provide a default audience for an entire Auth0 tenant, so I set this to be the same audience for my lone API. I am also able to obtain a valid token with scopes included on behalf of the Swagger UI application if I specify the grant type as client credentials (normally reserved for machine-to-machine auth). However, I can see from the Auth0 logs that the flow being used by the Swagger UI client is authorization code.